# How to set layout constraints with top layout guide?

Tags: ios

The code is:

```
    [self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:|-0-[button]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)]];
```

But the view is relative to superview, not the top layout guide.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/topLayoutGuide

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`|` refers to the superview, so you are creating a constraint that is pinning the view to the top of the superview.

You need to add the top layout guide as an item in your VFL string:

```
id guide = self.topLayoutGuide;
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[guide][button]"
                  options:0
                  metrics:nil
                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(guide,button)]];
```